# assembly still JIT after being ngened

Tags: .net, strongname, ngen

I have ngened an assembly (an exe with dependant dlls) and it runs fine. But when the computer is restarted and the application is run first time it runs in JIT mode and in subsequent runs it runs in ngened mode. Also when I tried to ngen the assembly with `ngen install myassembly.exe` the following message appears.

```
failed to compile strong name validation failed
```

I did the ngen process using Advanced Installer

Comment: Well, you have clear hint that something is rotten in Denmark.  Write an app.exe.config file with `<bypassTrustedAppStrongNames enabled="false" />` so strong names are always validated.  Fuslogvw.exe now ought to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: do i need to do that before ngening?